# Однотабличные запросы , SQL .

Tags: sql-server

Имеется часть вот такой БД :
[3 таблицы](http://imagepost.ru/?v=db_diag.png)

По заданию запрос должен быть без всяких Join-ов .
Само задание : `выбрать [name_groups] из таблицы [groups] для которых [id_student] == k .`
Что получилось у меня :

```
SELECT [name_group] FROM [group] WHERE EXISTS(SELECT [student_group].* FROM [student_group] 
WHERE [student_group].[id_group] = [group].[id_group] AND [student_group].[id_student] = 24)

/* или можно так */

SELECT [name_group] FROM [group] WHERE [id_group] = 
(SELECT [student_group].[id_group] FROM [student_group] WHERE
[student_group].[id_student] = 24)
```

Можно ли как-то сделать этот запрос более простым и не делать через подзапросы ?
Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Просто

```
select group.name_group from group, student_group where student_group.id_student = 24 and student_group.id_group = group.id_group
```

Конечно, это синтаксически другая форма `JOIN`, но по другому (без соединения таблиц) просто нелепо.